# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_order.default.addOrder')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I am trying to call the `addOrder` function from `CartScreen` to function located in my action folder.

the thing is whenever I pressed the **OrderNow** Button, the addOrder function should be triggered. But, I'm getting error like this.

[image]

**CartScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as cartAction from '../../store/actions/cart';
import ordersAction from '../../store/actions/order';
import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';
import CartItem from '../../components/shop/CartItem';

const CartScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartTotalAmount = useSelector(state => state.cart.totalAmount);
  const cartItems = useSelector(state => {
    const transformedCartItems = [];
    for (const key in state.cart.items) {
      transformedCartItems.push({
        productId: key,
        productTitle: state.cart.items[key].productTitle,
        productPrice: state.cart.items[key].productPrice,
        quantity: state.cart.items[key].quantity,
        sum: state.cart.items[key].sum,
      });
    }
    return transformedCartItems.sort((a, b) =>
      a.productId > b.productId ? 1 : -1,
    );
  });

  console.log('CATRITEM', cartItems);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.summary}>
        <Text style={styles.summaryText}>
          Total:{' '}
          <Text style={styles.amount}>${cartTotalAmount.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        </Text>
        <Button
          color={'green'}
          title="Order Now"
          disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
          onPress={() => {
            dispatch(ordersAction.addOrder(cartItems, cartTotalAmount));
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={cartItems}
        keyExtractor={item => item.productId}
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <CartItem
            quantity={itemData.item.quantity}
            title={itemData.item.productTitle}
            amount={itemData.item.sum}
            onRemove={() => {
              dispatch(cartAction.removeFromCart(itemData.item.productId));
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

CartScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: 'Your Cart',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  summary: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  summaryText: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  amount: {
    color: Colors.primary,
  },
});

export default CartScreen;
```

**order.js** (in action Folder)

```
export const ADD_ORDER = 'ADD_ORDER';

export const addOrder = (cartItems, totalAmount) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_ORDER,
    orderData: {
      items: cartItems,
      amount: totalAmount,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `import` differently and call the function as:

```
import { addOrder } from '../../store/actions/order';
```

Then call as the following:

```
dispatch(addOrder(cartItems, cartTotalAmount));
```

Comment: @Rooban Just updated the `import` section. Can you try as that?

Comment: @Rooban Awesome, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

your import is wrong . you imported orderAction like

```
import ordersAction from '../../store/actions/order';
```

what you should do is

```
import * as ordersAction from '../../store/actions/order';
```

things should work fine after